# git https commands with user:token authentication failed

Tags: git, https, gitlab

When trying to run git commands like:

git clone https://oauth2:{MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}@gitlab.myhost.com/abc123/myrepo.git

we get fatal: Authentication failed.   I have tried to no end to find a solution.  In Gitlab, my access token has all scopes enabled.

If I run git clone https://oauth2@gitlab.myhost.com/abc123/myrepo.git (without token) it prompts me for a password, which I enter my token and then it clones successfully.

So why on earth does it fail if I pass both the username AND token in the string together?

Comment: Does your token have any special characters in it?

Comment: I've revoked this token since I'm posting publicly:  PxFv_KsrKgaaSmD97ytt.  Not sure the underscore counts as a special character.